# SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans() sort order is wrong on nougat 7.0/7.1

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, spannablestringbuilder

the following code works on everything I try between 2.3 and 6.0.1 but fails 7.0/Emulator and 7.1.1/Nexus 6P

```
SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
for (int i=0;i<5;++i) {
    int p = spannableStringBuilder.length();
    spannableStringBuilder.append("aAAAAa\n");
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), p+1, p+5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}

boolean pass = true;
StyleSpan[] spans = spannableStringBuilder.getSpans(0, spannableStringBuilder.length(), StyleSpan.class);
int p = 0;
for (StyleSpan span : spans) {
    int start = spannableStringBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
    if (start<p) {
        pass = false;
        break;
    }
    p = start;
}
```

Comment: filed as bugreport https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229861

Comment: Could u please help me in this...Spannable.getSpanStart() is NOT giving the proper index in Marshmallow devices...What should i do now ???

Answer (score 3):

current workaround I am using

```
Arrays.sort(spans, new Comparator<ClickableSpan>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ClickableSpan o1, ClickableSpan o2) {
        return s.getSpanStart(o1)-s.getSpanStart(o2);
    }
});
```